# Trying to find bills that occurred during the opening hours of a bar - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find all the bills that occurred during the opening hours of the bar. Example:

```
|bills table           |      |bars table                 |
|billID |time  |name   |      |barName | barOpHr | barClHr|
|1      |22:00 |bar1   |      |bar1    | 20:00   | 03:00  |
|2      |15:00 |bar2   |      |bar2    | 19:00   | 02:00  |
|3      |23:35 |bar3   |      |bar3    | 22:00   | 03:00  |
```

Trying to achieve:

```
|bills table           |      
|billID |time  |name   |      
|1      |22:00 |bar1   |          
|3      |23:35 |bar3   |
```

My code looks like this:

```
select distinct b.billID from bills as b
inner join bars as s where s.name = b.bar 
and time_to_sec(time(b.time)) - time_to_sec(time(s.closing)) > '0'
and time_to_sec(time(b.time)) - time_to_sec(time(s.opening)) > '0'
```

It's not returning the right amount of rows, can someone tell me what my error is? Thank you.

Comment: what is type of `time` columns in your database?

Comment: I think your query would be returning you all 3 rows. You should change your condition to check the `time in bills table` to be after the `opening time in bars table`.

Comment: The time columns is varchar type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below :

```
select distinct b.billID, b.time, b.name
from bills as b inner join bars as s on s.name = b.barName 
where (
    time_to_sec(time(b.time)) - time_to_sec(time(s.barOpHr)) > '0'
    and time_to_sec(time(b.time)) - time_to_sec(time(s.barClHr)) > '0'
)
```

Please consider the usage of `JOIN`. additionally, I suggest you use an `ID` as primary key in `bars` table instead of name.